# Syntax errors creating an ASP.NET page using MonoDevelop

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop on Ubuntu to create ASP.NET pages. My code is producing syntax errors.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML
    1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head runat="server">
            <title>index</title>
            <script runat="server"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <p>Hello Word!</p>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> 1：/home/ublinuxyu/program/c#/index.aspx(0,0): Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<' (CS1525) (index)
>     2:/home/ublinuxyu/program/c#/index.aspx(4,4): Error CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @ (CS1646) (index)

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the build action of the aspx file to "Compile" instead of "Content".

You can fix it using the context menu on the file in the solution pad, or by using the property pad when that file is selected.

Comment: I have solved this problem！It's not the set build action of the aspx file ...  I didn't install the mono server in my computer system!